# Terraform Enterprise UI not recognizing all the GitHub Repositories

Tags: github, oauth, terraform, terraform-enterprise

Only few GitHub repositories are reflecting in Terraform Enterprise UI,
When established the connecting using GitHub OAuth. All the repositories are creating with same configuration and permissions. When trying to create the Terraform Enterprise workspace by connecting to the respective Github repo's, few repo's are reflecting in the search.

Comment: Without details in the question, the best guess is that some of the repos are not following the correct nomenclature. You can manually add those outside of the auto-search if that is the case.